# jquery get value of checked radio button on load or change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Got this script that gets the value of a checked radio button and prints it out in another tag. It works perfectly when you click a radio button, but I've realized that I need to have some of the radio buttons checked by default.

How do I change this script so that it will output the values of already checked radio buttons on page load as well?

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
    var radioValue = $(this).val();
    if(radioValue){
        $(this).closest('section').find('h2 .value').text(radioValue);
    }
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tactics/bykf31e6/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:checked` selector to find all the checked `:radio` elements on load, and the loop over them to set the value of the related `.value` element. Try this:

```
$(":radio:checked").each(function() {
    $(this).closest('section').find('h2 .value').text(this.value);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/bykf31e6/5/)

Note that you should use the `change` event for binding to radio and checkbox elements to cater for those who navigate websites using their keyboards. Also, if you remove the check that the radio element has a value (which is redundant as they should *always* have a value) you can simplify the code:

```
$("input[type='radio']").change(setText); // when user selects
$(":radio:checked").each(setText); // onload

function setText() {
    $(this).closest('section').find('h2 .value').text(this.value);
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/bykf31e6/9/)